# Why does my HTML website search in VBA keep returning the same dataset rather than updating?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code to extract option prices from the ASX website. The data is transferred to an array and copied into excel. A separate sub then strips out implied volatility estimations.

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=xjo&expiryDate=&optionType=B

The problem is the sub only works correctly when run for the first time. When run subsequently, the sub returns the previous dataset, rather than capturing new data on the website.

I included a test debug.print line within the code to demonstrate the problem:

The table object returns a bid of 148 and offer of 153 (row 110, columns 5 and 6) for the July 21, 5150 call (XJOEW7)--the exact same as when the sub was run earlier in the day. The correct prices on the ASX webpage are 178.30 (same bid/offer as the market is closed).

Why is the table object not capturing the new data on the webpage and instead returning earlier values?

```
Sub Data()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim xml As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim objTable As Object
Dim result As String
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lngTable As Long


'DATA SEARCH

Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With xml
    .Open "GET", "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=xjo&expiryDate=&optionType=B", False
    .send
End With

While xml.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

result = xml.responseText
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = result
Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("table")


Dim A() As Variant 'Output array
Dim i As Integer 'Row loop
Dim j As Integer 'Column loop


'TRANSFER DATA TO EXCEL

ReDim A(objTable(0).Rows.Length, objTable(0).Rows(1).Cells.Length) 'Resize output array

For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1

    For i = 0 To UBound(A, 1) - 1 'Row loop

        For j = 0 To UBound(A, 2) - 1 'Column loop

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'TEST CODE TO DEMONSTRATE PROBLEM

            If i = 110 Then

            Debug.Print objTable(lngTable).Rows(i).Cells(j).InnerText

            End If

            'END TEST CODE
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            A(i, j) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(i).Cells(j).InnerText

        Next j

    Next i

Next lngTable

With Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2)) 'Copy output array to excel

    .Name = "RawPrices"
    .Value = A
    .ClearFormats

End With


With Worksheets("Data").Range("RawPrices").Columns(2) 'Format dates

    .TextToColumns Destination:=Worksheets("Data").Range("RawPrices").Columns(2).Rows(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Call BlackScholes 'Call Newtown Raphson

End Sub
```

Comment: It may be some form of caching, try setting your `xml` object to nothing at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are calling the same URL everytime, it is a strong possibility that you are retrieving a cached version of the page and not hitting up the server for the latest data.

People use [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx) to work-around the known issues with XmlHttp and caching.

Here's sample code for retrieving the HTML using this alternative method. You can plug this function into your code posted in the question.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strHtml As String

    strUrl = "http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=xjo&expiryDate=&optionType=B"
    strHtml = GetHtmlString(strUrl)

    Debug.Print strHtml

End Sub

Function GetHtmlString(strUrl As String) As String

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strHtml As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With objRequest
        'synchronous call
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .Send
    End With

    GetHtmlString = objRequest.ResponseText

End Function
```